# What's low level Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've seen the term "Low level Javascript" come up a few times but I've no idea what it means. Google shows no results surprisingly. Can someone shed some light on it?

Comment: I think, it is pure javascript without using libraries like prototype or jquery

Comment: Karussell, you should post it as an answer, as that's what it is. It's also a comment on JS being a pain to use without a general-purpose library.

Comment: @Karussell: But the [Closure Library](http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/) is described as a "low level JavaScript library". That wouldn't make sense. :/

Comment: @Ben, in that case, I think "low level" applies to "library", not "JavaScript".

Comment: @Max S.: It's the browser DOM that's the pain. JS itself is a surprisingly good language, which is why it is possible to write elegant libraries in it.

Comment: This is also often referred to as "Vanilla Javascript" -- that is, JS without extra flavouring.

Comment: @Ben Shelock no, it makes totally sense: closure library does not depend on any other library ... low level js

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say it is "javascript without using cross-browser frameworks" such as jQuery or YUI.

Can be particularly tricky when it comes to supporting multiple browsers.

Comment: so... low level javascript is just javascript? What?

Answer (score 18):

As of 2012, someone saying "low level JavaScript" could be refering to [LLJS](http://mbebenita.github.com/LLJS/). It's a subset of JavaScript that compiles to a JavaScript code that is garbage collector friendly but unreadable (making heavy usage of WebGL typed arrays to manage memory).

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes people make up their own terms when they shouldn't. "Low level Javascript" is one of them. There's nothing "low level" about Javascript. It's interpreted at run-time inside an environment of high-level abstractions, like the DOM.

Comment: this is entirely opinionated and smells like hipster

Comment: Besides the reference to the LLJS project, every answer here is opinion.

Comment: Yea I do agree, but the question is real and "low level" JavaScript is actually a thing.. even though you're saying it isn't.. You're comparing JavaScript with other languages (apples and oranges). All logic is abstraction unless you're manipulating individual electrons and the fabric of space-time at it's most fundamental level, right? All I'm saying is: let's stick to JavaScript and explain what low level JavaScript is

Answer (score 2):

It's a very specialized tool that allows You to write CPU and Memory (explicit memory management, not GC) optimized JavaScript code. Using binary data, not standard JS objects and types.

Why? Because in some cases You need top performance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it means Javascript without any framework such as prototype/jQuery/YUI, which help with cross-browser compatibility, and generally provide a lot of useful functions, so you don't have to spend your time re-inventing the wheel.

Also, maybe it has something to do with the "new" way of doing Javascript -- i.e. object-oriented, using Frameworks, ... In opposition to the crappy code we used to seen a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 1):

low level JS is concise, precise code that executes efficiently, usually taking advantage of the language's intricacies

bitwise operation, type conversions / short circuit logical operators, prototype chaining, context binding, ternary assignation, event bubbling / propagation, object referencing, using the GPU, etc.